# Using the Event System to log deletions

Tags: event-system

I am having a problem logging deletions for pages when a structure group is deleted. The structure group deletion is logged but the pages in the structure group are not logged when the structure group is deleted. I am trying to do this by creating two events; the initiated and the committed but having problems. I am just not sure what to put in the initiated section and how to get the items to be deleted to the committed section Here is my code.

```
// We are getting all the objects deleted prior to it being deleted


      private void StructureGroupPreDeleteAction(StructureGroup subject, DeleteOrganizationalItemEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)

     {

         StringBuilder deletesg = new StringBuilder();

         foreach (var item in args.ItemsToDelete)
         {

         }

     }


    // Grab the objects the were collected before deletions and send them to the log.

    private void StructureGroupDeleteAction(StructureGroup subject, DeleteOrganizationalItemEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        string logDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");

        string fileName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}.{3}", logFilePath, deleteLogName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "txt");

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);

        tw.WriteLine(logDate + "itemsToDelete" );

        tw.Close(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't get a chance to figure out why I could not get Quirijin's solution to work. I did however get it to work(logging deletions for all items in a structure group, not just the structure group) with the following code;

```
// Subscribe to the post-StructureGroupDelete event
        EventSubscription deleteStructureGroup = EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<StructureGroup, DeleteOrganizationalItemEventArgs>(StructureGroupDeleteAction, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);

this.Subscriptions.Add(deleteStructureGroup);

private void StructureGroupDeleteAction(StructureGroup subject, DeleteOrganizationalItemEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {
        // Log the deletions of Structure groups. The pages and nested structure groups will be logged as well.
        string logDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");

        string fileName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}.{3}", logFilePath, deleteLogName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "txt");

        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);

        foreach (var items in args.ItemsToDelete)
        {
            tw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Deleted a [{1} ** {2}] {3} From: [{4}] | {5}:{6}[{7}]", logDate, subject.GetType().Name, items, items.Title, subject.WebDavUrl, subject.Session.User.Title, subject.Session.User.Description, subject.Session.User.Id));
        }

        // Fix this here for double logging
        tw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} Deleted a [{1} {2}] {3} From: [{4}] | {5}:{6}[{7}]", logDate, subject.GetType().Name, subject.Id, subject.Title, subject.WebDavUrl, subject.Session.User.Title, subject.Session.User.Description, subject.Session.User.Id));
        tw.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can collect information in the Pre-event and store it in the args.ContextVariables. In the Post-event you can read this information and use it.
Something like:

```
private void StructureGroupPreDeleteAction(StructureGroup subject, DeleteOrganizationalItemEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)

{

     StringBuilder deletesg = new StringBuilder();

     foreach (var item in args.ItemsToDelete)
     {
          deletesg.Append("deleting " + item.Title + ",");
     }
     args.ContextVariables.Add("itemsToDelete-" + subject.Id, deletesg.ToString());


 }


// Grab the objects the were collected before deletions and send them to the log.

private void StructureGroupDeleteAction(StructureGroup subject, DeleteOrganizationalItemEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
{
    string logDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("T");

    string fileName = String.Format(@"{0}\{1}.{2}.{3}", logFilePath, deleteLogName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "_"), DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "txt");

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);

    tw.WriteLine(logDate + "itemsToDelete: "  + args.ContextVariables["itemsToDelete-" + subject.Id]);

    tw.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't familiar with ContextVariables but realized later it is Tridion's way to work with a .Net dictionary. I will try this out. Thank you.

Comment: I am not getting an event error stating that the "The given key was not present in the dictionary." Any ideas?

Comment: The ID of the structure group folder I am deleting exists in the dictionary of the initiate phase method  StructureGroupPreDeleteAction .

Comment: Strange, Bryan. I have just implemented the same (or very similar) functionality and I have no trouble getting my values back from the ContextVariables in the Post action. Are you sure you are using the same key to put and to pull?

Comment: By the way, I corrected the code sample because the original could have caused errors with threading. The key now contains the Id of the subject.